# SQL pivot values to line chart - SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have SQL pivot, which works fine.. giving me report as below (demo figures)

```
 Receipts   Jan   Feb   Mar    Apr   May... Dec
 Cash-Rcpt  100   300   150    240   150
 CC-Rcpt    200   400   650    440   250
 Chq-Rcpt   300   100   950    840   350
```

Now i would like to create line chart beneath the same report, i'm not able to get receipts at y axis, months at x axis and values as lines

@Jonnus
thanks a lot for the reply, as its a SQL pivot, the data fields are appearing to me as below image
[image: monthly collection report design pane]

Answer (score 1):

While it's not clear what you mean by "receipts at y axis" is this the desired layout for your data?

[image]

This can be achieved by setting up the chart as follows.

[image]

If this the desired output, and you need further assistance, leave a comment and I can expand...

Comment: The dataset does not appear to have a `Month` column, there are individual month columns, `Jan`, `Feb`, etc.

Comment: Oh, well if you're returning a column for each month individually that's going to make it much harder to do.  Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @Jonnus i have added image to my post, if you can have a look at please

Comment: @Saifee Yes, I thought they might be how it looked. Pick be honest and say J don't think it is possible to get the chart your want with the fastest you have currently. The is no way for SSRS to assign different fields to the same series that I know of.

Comment: @Jonnus just as thought, as excel allows more than one data set in charts, is there anyway that SSRS can do?

Comment: @Saifee, no unfortunately as with most SSRS elements, only one dataset can be used in a chart (as set in the Properties -> DataSetName field)